# extrude on subdivision modifier

Tags: modeling, mesh, extrude

[image]

Hi, I'm taking a blender class and my modeling mesh does not appear like the picture above. So when I try to extrude, I keep ending up clicking big faces...
[image]

Comment: You haven't shown the modifier panel in your image but the instructor has the subdiv display turned off in his image (monitor icon at the top of the subdiv modifier). Incidentally the subtitle is wrong on his image! Press 3 for Face mode not 2 although his viewport image is correct.

Comment: hi, thanks for the comment. I tried turning the monitor icon but the object turns rectangular shape so how do I figure this out?

Comment: Without having access to the instruction video (which presumably is a paid-for course) and seeing your blend file which you can upload [here](https://pasteall.org/blend/) it's difficult to say.

Comment: think I happened to figure it out! thank you